# Tensorflow: troubleshoot tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn function

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm running some tutorial code from [text classification](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/text_classification.py.)

I can run the scripts and it worked but when I tried to run it line by line trying to understand what each step is doing, I got a bit confused at this step:

```
test_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
  x={WORDS_FEATURE: x_test},
  y=y_test,
  num_epochs=1,
  shuffle=False)
classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=100)
```

I know conceptually train_input_fn is feeding data to the training function but how I can manually call this fn to inspect what's in it?

I've traced the code and found out the train_input_fn function feeds data to the following 2 variables:

```
features
Out[15]: {'words': <tf.Tensor 'random_shuffle_queue_DequeueMany:1' shape=(560, 10) dtype=int64>}

labels
Out[16]: <tf.Tensor 'random_shuffle_queue_DequeueMany:2' shape=(560,) dtype=int32>
```

When I tried to evaluate the features variable by doing a sess.run(features), my terminal seems to get stuck and stops responding.

What's the right way to inspect content of variables like these?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [`numpy_input_fn` documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/inputs/numpy_input_fn) and the behaviour (hanging) I imagine the underlying implementation depends on a queue runner. Hanging occurs when queue runners aren't started. Try modifying your session running script to something like the following, based on [this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/threading_and_queues):

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    try:
        for step in xrange(1000000):
            if coord.should_stop():
                break
            features_data = sess.run(features)
            print(features_data)

    except Exception, e:
        # Report exceptions to the coordinator.
        coord.request_stop(e)
    finally:
        # Terminate as usual. It is safe to call `coord.request_stop()` twice.
        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)
```

Alternatively, I'd encourage you to check out the `tf.data.Dataset` interface (possible `tf.contrib.data.Dataset` in tensorflow 1.3 or prior). You can get similar input/labels tensors without using queues with `Dataset.from_tensor_slices`. Creation is slightly more involved, but the interface is much more flexible and the implementation doesn't use queue runners, meaning session running is much simpler.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x_data = np.random.random((100000, 2))
y_data = np.random.random((100000,))

batch_size = 2
buff = 100


def input_fn():
    # possible tf.contrib.data.Dataset.from... in tf 1.3 or earlier
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_data, y_data))
    dataset = dataset.repeat().shuffle(buff).batch(batch_size)
    x, y = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
    return x, y


x, y = input_fn()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run([x, y]))
```

Comment: Thanks DomJack. The code worked with a couple of minor changes on Python 3. I didn't think it's so complicated to just print out the value of a tensor in Tensorflow.

Comment: This is because of the queue runner implementation. I've edited my answer to include a dataset example you might find helpful. `Dataset`s are relatively new but once you get past a little bit of boilerplate I've found them incredibly simple, powerful and fast.

Comment: Thanks @DomJack. I'll definitely check it out. I've found it very counter-intuitive to debug Tensorflow code sometimes.